# remove <200b> character from text file

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, characters

I have a huge text file containing this string/character <200b> that I want to delete. I tried with sed but it didn't work.

> sed 's/<200b>//g' file

The character never shows when I open the file with a graphic text editor like gedit, I see it with vim.

Comment: Please see this link, it helped me find <200b> in my text file: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59447/replace-unicode-chars-in-vim

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[<200b> is a Unicode for "Zero Width Space"](https://unicode-table.com/en/200B/). You won't find it as a string. You can pipe the character into `sed` like this for removal:

```
sed -i "s/$(echo -ne '\u200b')//g" file
```

- [`sed -i`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) will modify the file in-place.
- `$(...)` is a [Bash command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html).
- [`echo` manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/echo):

  - `-n` do not output the trailing newline
  - `-e` enable interpretation of backslash escapes

Comment: Welcome to superuser: The answer maybe correct but would be better if it was surrounded with some detail on what you have done, how to use, etc. for people that may not understand and search answers in days or years to come.

Comment: there was no down vote from me

Comment: Combining [sed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8562661/4970442) and [`echo -ne`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8562354/remove-unicode-characters-from-textfiles-sed-other-bash-shell-methods#comment10614128_8562746) is even more elegant than [all this answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8562354/4970442)

Comment: I had to add an `-E` for it to work: `sed -iE "s/$(echo -ne '\u200b')//g" /tmp/s`

Comment: Using sed for this type of file clean-up job lends itself to automation if used in a bash script or similar. The idea is to remove these unwanted characters from a batch of pdf files converted to plain text characters using pdftotext in Linux at the command line.

Answer (score 32):

You can also get rid of this in VIM.

```
%s/\%u200b// - entire file
%s/\%u200b//g - entire file, more than one occurrence on a line
```

Comment: This is more straightforward for a single file cleanup because you get confirmation of how many characters were substituted and how many lines were found containing the target character. I used `:%s#\%u200b##g`. Where I chose to use the # character as a separator instead of the more common /, only a matter of preference.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend open this file in any Text editor and do a Find and Replace.

Find: Hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> and press <kbd>0</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>9</kbd> (this will input a zero-width character).

Replace: Leave empty.

Choose "Replace all".

Comment: Depending on how "huge" the text file is, some text editors won't work on it.

Comment: Hi. I already tried this but it tells me that the string is not found. The file has 5 million lines.

Comment: You have to detect how to input the same symbol as used in this file. And then use FART or Ser tool (as your file is really huge) to find and replace. I see no other option, but it doesn't mean it's not exist. Let's see if someone will post anything more effective.

Comment: I need to add an info. the character never shows when i open the file with a graphic text editor, i see it with vim.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone using vim and want to remove whole lines with this character, you can use the ex command `g`

```
:g/\%u200b/d
```